# What does it mean when one uses "class" as a datatype?

Tags: java, oop, variables, types, primitive-types

When using primitive datatypes, like char,int etc we know a number of bytes according to datatype are being reserved in memory, but what happens when we use a class as a datatype for a variable, since classes also have methods enclosed in them too, what happens or what does it mean to use class as a datatye for a variable(consider we are not instantiating the variable,only declaration), also how the methods are handled, are they a part of the variable ? And how does the different datatypes in that 'class'  are tied to single variable,which is using that class as a datatype. ?

Answer (score 0):

Class is non primitive data type so
Non-primitive data types are not defined by the programming language, but are instead created by the programmer. They are sometimes called "reference variables," or "object references," since they reference a memory location, which stores the data. In the Java programming language, non-primitive data types are simply called "objects" because they are created, rather than predefined. While an object may contain any type of data, the information referenced by the object may still be stored as a primitive data type